# How can an object get its key from a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, key, containment

Suppose I have a chessboard defined with a HashMap

```
HashMap <Position,Field> chessboard = new HashMap <Position,Field>();
```

I declare the `Position` as

```
class Position{
  int x;
  int y;
}
```

When I am trying to make a class for `Field` object I encounter a problem: the `Field` should contain a `Position` because it is defined by it. Ex.

```
class Field {
  Position pos;
  int color;
  void draw(){
    // draw Field using pos
  }
}
```

But the Position object is going to be used for HashMap.
How could I avoid this redundancy?

Comment: just remove it from `Field`. you can access it from `Map`

Comment: You can use the same `Position` object for your `Field` object and for the key in the `HashMap`.

Comment: Also, your HashMap won't work as expected unless you override `equals` and `hashCode` on `Position`.

Comment: When an object's key is part of that object's value, you shouldn't use a map, you should use a *set*.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's easy to access using `Map` when needed based on `Position`

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: why? It's quite useful, and a common scenario, to be able to quickly get books by their ISBN, or users by their ID, or whatever. The whole idea of a cache is based on this principle.

Comment: @JBNizet A *set* has that same property, it just makes the key and the value the same object, which makes it appropriate when the key is logically part of the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost isn't actually what you think: you're only holding a single reference (four bytes on most systems) to the same `Position` object in memory.  The overhead is minimal; don't even worry about it.